# Display Data based on Selected Items Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

After selecting data from a dropdown list how can I display a table by the selected data? For example: selected Employee and Month and I need to show table just this employee and from November.

[image: dropdown list]

**My Controller:**

```
public function look(Request $request)
{
    $routes = RouteInfo::all();
    return view('admin.look', compact('routes', $routes));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the field thar refers the months in the `RouteInfo` model ? and what is the relationship between Admin and RouteInfo models ?

Comment: Relationship is made between RouteInfo and User. Admin do nothing(sorry for confusing) Just working with AdminController and Admin View. That admin could select user and date and see needed information. Not sure about what you asking (What is the field thar refers the months in the RouteInfo model ?)

Comment: I mean if you choose November what field will you check in RouteInfo in where ? RouteInfo->WHAT = 'november' ?

Comment: "date" it looks like this in migrations: $table->dateTime('date');

Comment: Ok and where you choose the month you get `November` or `11` ??

Comment: i made by Carbon that date show just as Month. RouteInfo->date = 'november'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159066/discussion-between-maraboc-and-darius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
$routes = RouteInfo::whereHas('users', function ($query) use($request) {
                $query->where('id', $request->userId);
            })
            ->where('id', $request->monthId)
            ->get();
```

Ps : assuming that you have a :

- `users` relationship in the `RouteInfo` model.
- userName and month in your inputs names => `$request->userId` and `$request->monthId` else rename them to what you have !

Comment: There is no errors. But table is empty. i changed inputs names. but no luck, i will keep checking

Comment: @Marabloc Thank you for your help! It Works!

Comment: Happy to help ;)